# State parameter of circle not changing in thread class

Tags: java, multithreading, java-2d

I'm trying to explode and implode a circle , but the state of the circle doesn't change after explode is over so that it can implode. I'm using a thread for this circle. If i manually change the state  from the panel class where i draw my circle components the 2 methods(explode and implode) work. How can i change the state to implode after its done exploding from the circle class ?

This is the explode method :

```
public void explode()
    {
        double xCenter=thisBall.x+15;
        double yCenter=thisBall.y+15;

        if( (thisBall.x>xCenter-40) &&(thisBall.y>yCenter-40)&&(size<80))
        {
            thisBall.x--;
            thisBall.y--;
            size+=2;
            thisBall.setFrame(thisBall.x,thisBall.y,size,size);
        }
        else {state=2;}

    }
```

This is the implode method :

```
public void implode()
    {
        double xCenter=thisBall.x+40;
        double yCenter=thisBall.y+40;

        if((thisBall.x<xCenter) &&(thisBall.y<yCenter)&&(size>0))
        {
            thisBall.x++;
            thisBall.y++;
            size-=2;
            thisBall.setFrame(thisBall.x,thisBall.y,size+1,size+1);
        }
        else{state=3; }
```

And this is the run method for the class:

```
public void run()
    { while(state==1)
        {
            try {
                   Thread.sleep(40); 
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {  System.out.println("Thread Halted");}
            explode();

            controller.repaint(); // this is the panel where i draw the circle
        }
                while(state==2){
            try {
                   Thread.sleep(40); 
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {  System.out.println("Thread Halted");}
            implode();
            controller.repaint();
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *using a thread for this circle*? Are implode and explode called by different threads? Are the member variables declared volatile?

Comment: the circle class extends thread , i want to set state for explode manually, and after its done with the explosion i want the thread to implode the circle. There are not multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

If `state` is changed by one thread while another is executing the `run` method, there is a good chance that those changes are not visible since `state` is not fetched from memory again. Make it `volatile` and try again. Or use `AtomicInteger`.